# reset state to null or empty before recalculating the values of an Object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

**My question is how can I stop the object from adding the new state to old state, instead on every call set initial state to null or empty and reassign data?**

I have a state defined in my component like below

```
const [groupOfSponsors, setGroupOfSponsors] = useState<{ [key: string]: number }>({});
```

And after I do re-fetch and call below method I want the groupOfSponsors object to be set to null or empty and then reassign the key value pairs, currently its keeping the old state and adding new state to the the old state so imagine if there was

`initial State = {}`

After Data Fetch state becomes `{ "INVALIDATED": 1, "POSTED": 352 }`
if you click the fetch button again, state becomes `{ "INVALIDATED": 2, "POSTED": 704 }` whereas it should have been `{ "INVALIDATED": 1, "POSTED": 352 }` since it fetched the same records again.

```
function calcGroupofSponsors(data: any) {
  data?.forEach(function (value: ISponsorDetails) {
    if (Object.keys(groupOfSponsors).includes(value.status)) {
      groupOfSponsors[value.status] = groupOfSponsors[value.status] + 1;
    } else {
      groupOfSponsors[value.status] = 1;
    }
  });
  const tmp = {...groupOfSponsors};
  setGroupOfSponsors(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question/issue correctly you want `calcGroupofSponsors` to start from a "clean" copy of the initial state, e.g. `{}`. Instead of referencing the outer `groupOfSponsors` closed over in callback scope you can declare a new locally scoped `groupOfSponsors` that is set to the value `{}` and populated as the `data` array is processed.

Example:

```
function calcGroupofSponsors(data: ISponsorDetails[] = []) {
  const groupOfSponsors = {};

  data.forEach((value: ISponsorDetails) => {
    if (!groupOfSponsors[value.status]) {
      groupOfSponsors[value.status] = 0;
    }
    groupOfSponsors[value.status]++;
  });

  setGroupOfSponsors(groupOfSponsors);
}
```

This pattern could also instead be an `Array.prototype.reduce`.

Example:

```
function calcGroupofSponsors(data: ISponsorDetails[] = []) {
  groupOfSponsors = data.reduce((groupOfSponsors: { [k: string]: number }, value: ISponsorDetails) => {
    if (!groupOfSponsors[value.status]) {
      groupOfSponsors[value.status] = 0;
    }
    groupOfSponsors[value.status]++;
    return groupOfSponsors;
  }, {});

  setGroupOfSponsors(groupOfSponsors);
}
```